# Group of mappings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid

Is there a group $G$ of mappings $X \to X$ that has a non-bijective map in it? I mean, for each element of G, it must has its inverses at right and left, and those must be the same, so the element is necessarily bijective, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Take the zero map $X\rightarrow X$ of a vector space $X$. Then it forms a group, the trivial group. But the map is not invertible. More generally, take the additive group of matrices $M_n(K)$. It contains the zero map.

Comment: Fine until the "more generally": $M_n(K)$ is not a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand on Dietrich Burde's comment, if you take an idempotent $e$ in any transformation semigroup, then $\{e\}$ is a trivial group. Moreover an idempotent transformation is not necessarily a permutation.

Actually, if you take the transformation semigroup $T_n$ on $n$ elements, it contains several groups apart from the permutation group $S_n$, including non-trivial ones.